# Why am I not able to run swirl in Rstudio?

Tags: r, windows, rstudio, windows-8.1, swirl

I am on Windows 8.1 and am running R 3.2.2 in RStudio and am trying to install the package swirl.  I used the command install.packages("swirl") and it installs successfully, but when I enter library(swirl), Rstudio fails to take any further action and eventually crashes.

What is causing this issue and can I fix it?

I have already tried deleting and reinstalling R, Rstudio and swirl several times without any success, nor did I find better ideas online.

[image]

Comment: post the error please..have you checked that it installed successfully..

Comment: just do `library(swirl)` not `library(swirl_2.2.21.zip)`

Comment: http://imgur.com/0cN7TaQ

Comment: library(swirl) doesn't work either.  Rstudio takes the command and then after about five minutes it displays "R encountered a fatal error"

Comment: can you also post the version of rstudio..you can view it by using cmd `rstudion::versionInfo()`

Comment: The version is 0.99.484

Comment: its surely going out of memory for some reason..with the same versions of  R and Rstudio swirl is working for me. Try uninstalling `swirl` completely first using `remove.packages("swirl")` check in your `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\library` that its removed completely. Try giving a shot again.

Comment: Will do.  Thank you.